# array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using angular as the front end and php at the backend.

I am trying to post some data as array from angular to php and get the error `array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array` in console.

**angular.js**

```
var form_data_head = {};
form_data_head['doc_no'] = $scope.add.doc_no;
form_data_head['date'] = $scope.add.tanggal;
form_data_head['requisitor'] = $scope.add.requisitor;

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "api/config/function-insert.php",
  data: {
    form_data_head: form_data_head,
    tablename: 'pr_head',
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
}).then(function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
}, function(response){
  console.log("failed");
})
```

**php**

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';

$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$table_name = $request->tablename;
$form_data_head = $request->form_data_head;

$fields = array_keys($form_data_head);

$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (`".implode('`,`', $fields)."`) VALUES('".implode("','", $form_data_head)."')";
return $mysqli->query($sql);
?>
```

is it wrong way to pass the array from angular to php?

**UPDATE**

this is what i get from the console if i add `var_dump($request->form_data_head);`

```
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
  ["doc_no"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["date"]=>
  string(24) "2016-05-10T04:26:02.857Z"
  ["requisitor"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: `$request->form_data_head` isn't an array. Use `var_dump($request->form_data_head)` to see what's in it, then make sure it's the array you want.

Comment: added the detail in the question.

Comment: You can try it $form_data_head = (array)$request->form_data_head;

Comment: @MukeshRam nice, it works,  but why in angularjs `new Date()` will returned `2016-05-10T04:26:02.857Z`, how can to get the date only without the time. and could please post it as an answer?

Comment: @JosephGoh - date you are getting is with timezone so you have to format the date before you send to server.
use this 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

or you can format date in ajax file after $fields = array_keys($form_data_head);
add this

$fields['date']  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($fields['date']));

Answer (score 1):

```
json_decode($postdata, false)
```

Turns your json into StdClass

```
json_decode($postdata, true)
```

Turns your json into array

```
$request = json_decode($postdata,true);

$table_name = $request['tablename'];
$form_data_head = $request['form_data_head'];

$fields = array_keys($form_data_head);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: what the different between turn json into array and `(array)Object` ?

Comment: If you would want only $form_head_data as an array yet the $request as a stdClass, typecasting would be the solution. @Mukesh Ram